# mosaic-style image grid, floats and margins

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, padding

My homepage is a series of small images(used for navigation) arranged to create a perfect rectangle.

My plan was initially to use `<ul>` and some creative use of `float` and `margin` but I'm no longer sure that is the best option.

What is the simplest way I can achieve this effect?

```
<div class="home-nav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">weddings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portraits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div><!-- end home-nav -->
```

[image: Image mosaic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a JavaScript plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), or the simple-yet-effective [Wookmark jQuery Plugin](http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin) (my personal favorite). However, for such a simple layout, it may not be worth the overhead.

I think you're on the right track with using `float:left`. However, you'll need to group the two boxes in the upper-left in order to achieve the desired effect without using JavaScript.

Also, since this isn't really a *list*, I would use the HTML5 `<nav>` tag instead of `<ul>` and `<li>`. Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S3AxK/) to see a working example of the code below).

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  width: 315px;
}
nav a {
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 105px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(2) {
  width: 155px;
  height: 105px;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3) {
  width: 155px;
  height: 105px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
nav div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(4) {
  width: 155px;
  height: 105px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

I tend to prefer minimal HTML markup at the expense of more complex CSS, which is why I'm using the `:nth-child` extensively, but you could achieve the same effect using class names instead.

Comment: This was the smart, simple solution I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This type of arrangement is accomplished automatically with a bin-packing algorithm. There are several JavaScript libraries that do this, the most popular one is [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Or you can use @David's suggestion above if you don't need automatic arrangement.